# How many ways to order 26 letters so that the strings lift and graph are not included?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I just need to **subtract** the letters used by the strings? or is just removing the ordering of the words?

Comment: It's probably easier to count the number of orderings where the two strings *are* included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

- $S$ be the set of all possible permutations with no restrictions
- $L \subseteq S$ contain all permutations with the string "lift"
- $G \subseteq S$ contain all permutations with the string "graph"
- $B \subseteq S$ contain all permutations with both of the strings "lift" and "graph"

Then by the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, it follows that the number of strings where both strings are not included is:
\begin{align*}
|S| - (|L| + |G|) + |B|
&= 26! - ((26 - 4 + 1)! + (26 - 5 + 1)!) + (26 - 4 - 5 + 2)! \\
&= 26! - (23! + 22!) + 19! \\
&= 403264485230784073408512000
\end{align*}